# Import excel file through php into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, excel

I facing a problem regarding the import of an excel file into mysql through php.
i have used phptriad as a local server to test my web application(site).
The application imports the excel file present on the client side computer.
the code works fine when accessed through local server.

recently i have registered a subdomain at orgfree.com.
i have uploaded all the application files onto the site.
but 'importing excel file' function does not work.
it shows 'the file D:\test.xls is not readable' error(test.xls is on my laptop).

what could be the solution to this problem? please help

**Here is the code**

```
require_once 'reader.php';
$excelrow=0;$excelcol=0;                    
function parseExcel($excel_file_name_with_path)
{
    global $excelrow,$excelcol;
    $data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
    // Set output Encoding.
    $data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
    $data->read($excel_file_name_with_path);
    $colname=array('id','name');                    
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $data->sheets[0]['numRows']; $i++)
        {
            for ($j = 1; $j <= $data->sheets[0]['numCols']; $j++)
            {
              $product[$i-1][$j-1]=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j];
              $product[$i-1][$colname[$j-1]]=$data->sheets[0]['cells'][$i][$j];
            }
        }
    $excelrow=$i;$excelcol=$j;
    return $product;
}
$data=parseExcel($file);

for($i=0;$i<$excelrow-1;$i++)
{
    for($j=0;$j<$excelcol-1;$j++)
    {
        $fname=ucfirst(strtolower($data[$i][0]));
        $lname=ucfirst(strtolower($data[$i][1]));
        $gender=ucfirst(strtolower($data[$i][2]));
        $phoneno=$data[$i][3];
            $email=strtolower($data[$i][4]);                            
        $occup=ucfirst(strtolower($data[$i][5]));
        $city=ucfirst(strtolower($data[$i][6]));                
    }
        //THEN INSERT INTO DATABASE THROUGH SQL QUERIES                     
}
```

note: there is only one user to the application i.e., Administrator.

Comment: Do you have the correct file permissions?

Comment: Well, this question is thorougly unanswerable as long as you don't show some code. For what it's worth though, the "D:\test.xls" sounds like your file upload is accessing the `name` parameter in the FILES array and not `tmp_name`

Comment: sorry but what is 'name' parameter and 'tmp_name' parameter?

Comment: please note: i have used a excel reader file which i downloaded.

Comment: @PVB as I said, you will need to show some code to get answers

Comment: @PVB nothing in this code shows a file upload. You are aware that when running this script on server side, you have no access to your local files?

Comment: so what you say is that i have to upload it onto the site folder and then import the excel file???

Comment: @PVB yup, more or less. See my answer

Comment: is there any way i can upload the file automatically?

Comment: @PVB theoretically, yes, you could have a synchronization program monitor a local folder, and upload anything new in there to the server using FTP. I have seen related questions on SO and superuser.com, but can't find any right now, you'd have to search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably the fact that when running a script on a remote server, you will not have access to your local files any more. This happened to work when the server was running on the local machine, but the remote server has no way of seeing your computer's files.

You would have to add an upload facility. A rudimentary example is outlined in the [PHP manual on file uploads.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php)

Alternatively, if you want to use this only for yourself and not as a public service, you could also upload each Excel file to the remote server using FTP, and change the path accordingly to match the new location.